# Simple method of calling an API from Kotlin

Tags: android, string, api, kotlin, binary

In my quest to learn Kotlin I am trying to write an Android app that will take 3 photos and upload them in binary format to my database via an API.

Thanks to the help of people here and the Google documentation, I have been able to get my 3 photos and display a nice thumbnail image for each one. I have also worked out how to save the image to a physical file. I don't want to physically save the file first (not least because I'd still have to upload it to the database somehow). What I'm struggling with though is (a) converting the file to binary and (b) calling an API.

I get the file(s) into a variable using:

```
val imageBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
```

This is within:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
```

So, at this point I have a variable (imageBitmap) which is holding the photo. My API;

```
http://api.domain.com/api/photos?key={APIkey}&ipaddress=1.1.1.1&activity=new&imgdate=2021-05-04&img=x0x0x0x0x0
```

is structured as above (img is the aspect that I need to pass the photo image through). Is it as simple as:

```
urlString = "http://api.domain.com/api/photos?key={APIkey}&ipaddress=1.1.1.1&activity=new&imgdate=2021-05-04&img=" + imageBitmap
```

Would the above not be invalidly trying to concatenate a string and an object?

The API is written in C# through Visual Studio and calls a stored proc in my database. The img parameter in the proc is varbinary(max) so base64 encoded.

I found a lot of references to using OKHttp3, but I can't find an example that is clear enough for a beginner. What I was envisaging was that I'd call a function that encompasses the call and returns the json response. I took the code below from an example, and whilst it doesn't error, it doesn't make a call either:

```
fun doAPICall(url: String, body: String): String {
  val apiClient = OKHttpClient()
  var resp: String = ""
  val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

  //Define the body if present

  apiClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {}
    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
      resp = response.body()?.string()!!
    }
  })
}
```

So, I have two problems that I'm struggling to understand here. Firstly how do I convert imageBitmap into a binary string that I can pass in the API as a part of the url parameter, and secondly, how do I call the API and get the response back?

I tried a very simple example to see if the code worked by just calling an API and trying to write the response value to a TextView:

```
txtResponse.text = doAPICall("http://api.domain.com/api/photos?key={APIkey}&ipaddress=1.1.1.1&activity=getName", "")
```

This doesn't throw an error, but doesn't put the response into the textview either. The response for this should be:

```
{
    "APIResult": [
        {
            "id": 200,
            "status_message": "Success",
            "name": "Testing"                
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone provide some pointers for me please?

Comment: `struggling with though is (a) converting the file to binary ` A file is just a lot of bytes. You should upload those bytes if you wanna upload a file. The type of file is irrelevant.

Comment: `I convert imageBitmap into a binary string ` ?? You wanna upload a file so where does a bitmap come in play? No bitmap needed to upload the bytes of a file.

Comment: `So, at this point I have a variable (imageBitmap) which is holding the photo. ` Wel... You said you managed to make a file out of it. So now you can upload that file i would think. For me i cannot follow your story... Can you edit your post to make the steps clear?

Comment: It would not be bad also to tell at the start how the receiving server expects you to upload a file. Just the bytes of the file? Or maby the bytes of the file base64 encoded. In which case you would upload a base64 encoded string. Put it all in your post please to write a decent story which we can follow.

Comment: "A file is just a lot of bytes. You should upload those bytes if you wanna upload a file". Yes, I understand that the file is made up of bytes. What I'm asking though is how I convert that variable into a binary string that I can append to the URL for the API call. Is it as simple as: urlString = "http://api.domain.com/api/photos?key={APIkey}&ipaddress=1.1.1.1&activity=new&imgdate=2021-05-04&img=" + imageBitmap. Sorry if It wasn't clear.

Comment: "tell at the start how the receiving server expects you to upload a file": I have written the API in VisualStudio. These are published and I can call them through Postman. The API calls a stored procedure on my SQL Server to upload the data. The binary string (last parameter in the call) is passed to a varbinary(max) in SQL Server which is stored in a varbinary column

Comment: You are not reacting to all the things i said. Further i have no idea what you mean with a binary string. And putting files in a query string of an url will not go as query strings are very limited in size. You cannot use a GET request. Use POST.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, blackapps. I edited the post to clarify. The API to upload the photos is a post not get. I can't see where I mentioned it's a get, but perhaps that's implied in the function. I'm using the function to test (that is a get). The photos will be reasonably small and they'll be uploaded one by one, so the string (in the example img=x0x0x0x0x0) is the representation of the photo for the upload. If this is too big for a QS, I'm happy to pass it through the body. I tested a 136kb image and it is quite long. Does this clarify what I'm asking for help with?

Comment: I have no idea how you obtained img=x0x0x0x0x0 or what you wanna say with it. A 0x prefix for a hexadecimal notation? Then your 136KB file would expand to four times as large. And if you have to POST i do not understand that you test with GET.

Comment: x0x0x0 isn't actual data. It's just an example to illustrate what I'm looking to achieve, rather than putting a huge binary string that doesn't add anything to the question, just as the actual api isn't on api.domain.com. The reason I am testing with a get is because the url is simpler and the response is simpler. If someone is able to help me understand how to make a call in the first place, I would hope that I could work out the rest myself. I'm just looking for some help in understanding broad principles and pointers for the right direction. I'm not looking to argue coding best practices.